# Is it possible to exclude directories from CLions coverage interface to gcov?

Tags: c++, testing, code-coverage, clion, gcov

Is it possible to exclude directories from CLion's interface to gcov / gcovr? Its a great tool but I have like 40% coverage because lots of third party directories are being included, including googletest. I've heard that other coverage tools use an exclude file, a bit like a `.gitignore`, which would be great.